# R, Dataset without column names

Tags: r, database, dataframe, dataset

Complete noob here, specially with R.

For a school project I have to work with a specific dataset which doesn't come with column names in the dataset it self but there is a .txt that has extra information regarding the dataset, including the column names. The problem I'm having is that when I load the dataset rstudio assumes that the first line of data is actually the column names. Initially I just substituted the name with colnames() but by doing so I ended up ignoring/deleting the first line of data, and I'm sure that's not the right away of dealing with it.

How can I go about adding the correct column names without deleting the first line of data? (Preferably inside R due to school work requirements)

[image: What happens when I just load the dataset without doing anything]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `read.table` function has options to provide column names (`header = FALSE` by default). For example `read.table(file = 'yourfile.txt', col.names = youcolnames)`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  header = FALSE by itself solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we read the data with `read.table`, use `header = FALSE` so that it automatically assigns a column name

```
df1 <- read.table('file.txt', header = FALSE)
```

Then, we can assign the preferred column names from the other `.txt` column

```
colnames(df1) <- scan('names.txt', what = '', quiet = TRUE)
```

Comment: All I needed was header = FALSE . Thank you!